# Where is Grothendieck's “Résidus et Dualité: Prénotes pour un Séminaire Hartshorne”?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

About the book *Residues and Duality*, from R. Hartshorne, Giacomo Aiello wrote in a footnote to [Grothendieck's bibliography by topic](https://www.williamstein.org/sga/aiello/AIELLO%20-%20Grothendieck%27s%20Bibliography.pdf):

> This is the famous seminar held by Robin Hartshorne at Harvard in the academic year 1963/64. It is the developments of the duality theorems sketched by Grothendieck seven years before [57]. From 1957 to 1963 Grothendieck was so busy with EGA and SGA that he had not materially time to redact his ideas. A part of this redactional work was made by Jean Louis Verdier in his thesis, where he introduced the so-called “derived categories”, the correct frame where Grothendieck’s duality could be developed in a rigorous way. In Spring 1963, Robin Hartshorne (at that time in
> Harvard), offered to Grothendieck to run a seminar about [57] if he had redacted the material. Grothendieck accepted and in a few months wrote a massive manuscript (never published) of 250 pages called “Résidus et Dualité: Prénotes pour un Séminaire Hartshorne”. But his notes were too much general and Hartshorne had to simplify them using the best restrictive hypotheses. The result of his efforts is [73]. However, the work of Hartshorne contains some highly not trivial errors, corrected only many decades after by Brian Conrad, in Grothendieck Duality and Base-Change, Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1750 (2000) (and some addendum).

I am interested in finding a copy (physical or digital) of Grothendieck's manuscript *Résidus et Dualité: Prénotes pour un Séminaire Hartshorne*. A google search just shows people citing the manuscript, but no clue of where to find it. The Grothendieck circle seems not to have it on their webpage.

Hartshorne, in *Residues and Duality*, quotes the introduction of *Résidus et Dualité*:

> Les présentes notes donnent une esquisse assez détaillée d'une théorie cohomologique de la dualité des Modules cohérents sur les préschémas. Les idées principales de la théorie m'étaient connues dès 1959, mais le manque de fondements adéquats d'Algèbre Homologique m'avait empêché d'aborder une rédaction d'ensemble. Cette lacune de fondements est sur le point d'être comblée par la thèse de VERDIER, ce qui rend en principe possible un exposé satisfaisant. Il est d'ailleurs apparu depuis qu'il existe des théories cohomologiques de dualité formellement très analogues a celle développée ici dans toutes sortes d'autres contextes: faisceaux cohérents sur les espaces analytiques, faisceaux abéliens sur les espaces topologiques (VERDIER), modules galoisiens (VERDIER, TATE), faisceaux de torsion sur les schémas munis topologie étale, corps de classe en tous genres… Cela me semble une raison assez sérieuse pour se familiariser avec le yoga général de la dualité dans un cas type, comme la théorie cohomologique des résidus.
>
> La théorie consiste pour l'essentiel dans des questions de variance: construction d'un foncteur $f^!$ et d'un homomorphisme-trace $\underline{\underline{R}}f_*f^!\to\operatorname{id}$. La construction donnée  ici est compliquée et indirecte et n'est pas valable sous des conditions aussi générales qu'on est en droit de s'y attendre. Il faudra sans doute une idée nouvelle pour apporter des simplifications substantielles.

Comment: I think the best we can possibly have is to ask Hartshorne. I do not think the notes were distributed or copied massively.

Comment: These notes by Grothendieck will be published by the smf in 2024

Comment: @user234212323 Has the SMF publicly announced it somewhere? A Google search doesn't give results.

Comment: Private communication